# Number of results on a google search

Tags: android, google-search, bing-search

i'm new on android studio and on this site, so i'm sorry if i made some error or if i m not clear.

In my app i need the number of results in a google/Bing search of 3 word inserted by the User, and the User must not see the search, but just the output.

I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify your question a little bit more. What do you mean by that you don't want user to see the search, but just the output?

At a high level implementation could be something like this. User will provide a search term in your front-end. From your front-end you will make a call to your middle tier. Your middle tier will make a call to Bing APIs and get a response. Middle tier will apply some business logic to the response (e.g. selecting part of the data) and then send it back to your front end to display.

Does this answer your question? If not, please add more detail in your question.